# Excel: AGGREGATE function with an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm referring to the data below, and I would like to calculate a conditional mean:

```
2 
0
#N/A
0
0
0
0
-2
20
0
25
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
154
25
0
120
0
0
0
0
0
-2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
57
0
-57
1299
0
0
0
0
0
#N/A
0
#N/A
0
0
0
-25
0
0
0
0
0
-5
5
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
20
0
-25
0
-20
0
0
-10
0
20
0
#N/A
#N/A
25
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I'm using the formula below:

```
{=AGGREGATE(1,6,IF(A1:A1000<0,A1:A1000))}
```

It's throwing up a value error, not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arrays* (as opposed to *Range References*) can only be passed to `AGGREGATE` when that function has an initial parameter of 14 or greater; in all other cases the argument passed as `AGGREGATES`'s third parameter must be a reference to an actual worksheet range (or else some construction which resolves as such).

The fact that you are using a second parameter of 6 suggests that you are not concerned with having a formula which takes into account hidden rows within the range. As such, and since `AVERAGEIF` ignores errors, I would advise:

`=AVERAGEIF(A1:A1000,"<0")`